# Eclipse refactor overridden method into final and abstract parts

Tags: eclipse, refactoring

I have a method which i'd like to refactor

Basically i want to split the top level method in a abstract and a final part.
The method in question is overridden in quite a few places where additional functionality is added, but eventualy the super call is always made.

The code now basically look like:
(not all Extending classes override but those that do, do it this way)

```
class Base {

public Object getStuff(String key) {
 out = //code to get data from the Database.
 return out
}

class Extended1 extends Base {
   public Object getStuff(String key) {
      if("some_non_db_value".equals(key)) {
         return "some custom stuff";
      }
      return super.getStuff(key);
    }
}
```

What i'd like as a result would be something like:

```
class Base {

public final Object getStuff(String key) {
   out = getCustom(key);
   if(out != null) {
      return custom;
   }

   out = //code to get data from the Database.
   return out
}

public abstract Object getCustom(String key);
```

}

```
class Extended1 extends Base {
   public Object getCustom(String key) {
      if("some_non_db_value".equals(key)) {
         return "some custom stuff";
      }
      return null;
    }
}
```

I was hoping there would be a refactor action (or partial refactor) to get to (or closer to) this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first rename getStuff() to getCustom() which would take care of all the extended classes. Then changing the Base class should be relatively easy.